# I'd like to change specified UDID in .ipa

Tags: ipa, udid, xcode-server

Do you know how I can change the UDIDs in .ipa file without Xcodes?
I got test version of my app from my programmer. But I don't want to bother him, because he is super busy.

Answer (score 0):

To change UDID in your .ipa you need to resign this ipa using certificate (p12 file) and new mobileprovision. You can do this using XCode or command line tools.

I think you won't be able to do this without iOS-developer.